# HTML Zooming element with dimensions defined in percents as if it was defined in pixels

Tags: javascript, html, css

This question is quite trivial and I'm kinda scared to ask it, but I have been looking for answer and couldn't find it anywhere.

Let's say we have a HTML element, which dimensions are defined in pixels:

```
<div style="width:750px; height: 250px"></div>
```

We can easily zoom it. It resizes.

If the size is defined in percents, however...

```
<div style="width:75%; height: 25%"></div>
```

it does not resize if we zoom it. The size is constant and always takes 75% width and 25% height, no matter how zoomed it is.

I would like it to be scalable - to load with size proportional to user screen, but then if he decides to zoom in or out allow him to do so and treat the element as if it was defined in pixels. How can I achieve that?

Comment: You'll need to have a parent container which size is defined in pixels.

Comment: @EasyBB Yes! That was exactly what I was looking for. I added simple script detecting user window size and changed style of parent container to that size and it works just as intended! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you can't do both, you have to chose . But personally, I prefer working with px ...